# Not able to call Jenkins shared library in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, shared-libraries, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to implement jenkins shared library, the code is in https://github.com/DeekshithSN/shared-library for the reference. i have only one function i.e, under var folder as shown in below picture 
[image]

In jenkins i have referenced the same , as shown below

[image]

but when tried calling in my jenkinsfile, it fails with **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'filterLogs' found among steps**

Jenkinsfile

```
pipeline{

      agent {
                docker {
                image 'maven'
                args '-v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2'
                }
            }

        stages{

              stage('Quality Gate Status Check'){
                  steps{
                      script{
                                sh "mvn clean install"
                          }
                     }  
                 }  

                 stage ('Check logs') {
                    steps {
                        filterLogs ('WARNING', 2)
                    }
                }

           }                             
}
```

Comment: You need to either 1. check Load Implicitly in the global config 2. load it explicitly within the `Jenkinsfile`. Your choice as to which you want to do here.

Comment: See [Using Libraries](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#using-libraries)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to always load it explicitly within the Jenkinsfile, as per @Matt suggestion nr2.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

@Library('shared-library@master') _ //master or whatever branch

pipeline {
...
```

Comment: i have used explicitly calling in jenkinsfile, it worked for me